# Unexpected outcome in text analysis using R with gutenbergr and cv.glmnet

Tags: r, text, glmnet

hope that all of you are fine,

I'm trying to replicate a text analysis exercise ir `R` with the `gutembergr` library, and trying to run a machine learning model with the `glmnet` library.

The problem is that the code actually runs, but it returns the wrong outcome.

I leave the full code, which is not very extensive and is fully replicable.

## First part of the code, runs fine

```
##### Carga de librerias sajtas #####

library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(udpipe)
library(gutenbergr)
library(rsample)
library(glmnet)
library(yardstick)

##### 1. Cargar los libros del gutenberg ####

twist_tale <- gutenberg_metadata %>%
  filter(
    title %in% c("A Tale of Two Cities", "Oliver Twist"),
    has_text,
    language == "en") %>%
  pull(gutenberg_id) %>%
  gutenberg_download(meta_fields = "title")

##### 2. Quitarle los blancos #####

twist_tale <- twist_tale %>%
  filter(text != "")

View(twist_tale)

##### 3. Crear la varialbe lógica ######

twist_tale <- twist_tale %>%
  mutate(
    es_two_cities = case_when(
      title == "A Tale of Two Cities" ~ 1L,
      title == "Oliver Twist" ~ 0L
    ),
    line_id = row_number()
  )%>%
  view()

##### 3.1. Guardar los resultados y contar las filas ####

twist_tale %>%
  count(title)

##### 4. Preparar el dataset y modelar #####

dl <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
english_model <- udpipe_load_model(dl$file_model)

text <- twist_tale %>%
  select(doc_id = line_id, text)

twist_tale_preprocesado <- udpipe(text, english_model, parallel.cores = 4L)

##### 4b. crear un algoritmo de entrenamiento #####

set.seed(1234L)
twist_tale_split <- initial_split(twist_tale)
twist_tale_training <- training(twist_tale_split)
twist_tale_testing <- testing(twist_tale_split)

##### 4a. Ponerlo en minúsculas y quitarle la mugre ####

sparse_train_data <- twist_tale_preprocesado %>%
  mutate(lemma = str_to_lower(lemma)) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = c("lemma" = "word")) %>%
  filter(upos %in% c("PUNCT", "SYM", "X", "NUM")) %>%
  mutate(doc_id = as.integer(doc_id)) %>%
  anti_join(twist_tale_testing, by = c("doc_id" = "line_id")) %>%
  count(doc_id, lemma) %>%
  cast_sparse(doc_id, lemma, n)
```

Until here, everything is fine. The problem arises running the `cv.glmnet()` model, since it doesn't return any error or warning message, but the outcome is a row vector, and I believe that it must be a matrix or tibble.

```
# The code that presents the problem

##### 5a. Excluir los resultados irrelevantes y guardarlos ####

y <- twist_tale_training %>%
  filter(line_id %in% rownames(sparse_train_data)) %>%
  pull(es_two_cities)

##### 6a. Calcular la regresión logística regularizada ####

model <- cv.glmnet(sparse_train_data, y, family = "binomial", 
                   keep = T, trace.it=1)           # THE PROBLEM IS ACTUALLY HERE

coeficientes <- model$glmnet.fit %>%
  tidy() %>%
  filter(lambda == model$lambda.1se)

coeficientes %>%
  group_by(estimate > 0) %>%
  slice_max(estimate, n = 5) %>%
  ungroup()

coeficientes %>%
  group_by(estimate > 0) %>%
  slice_max(estimate, n = 5) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = fct_reorder(term, estimate), y = estimate, fill = estimate > 0)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

I Apologize for the extent of the question but was for showing the full context.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't run your code but probably you need to make sure the x matrix and y response vector are in the same order. Something alongside the following will do that (replacing step 5a. and the beginning of your step 6)

```
library(udpipe)
y         <- setNames(twist_tale_training$es_two_cities, twist_tale_training$line_id)
traindata <- dtm_align(x = sparse_train_data, y = y)
model     <- cv.glmnet(x = traindata$x, y = traindata$y, family = "binomial", keep = T, trace.it = 1)
```